# "No version is set for command npm" .tool-versions file missing

Tags: node.js, npm, config

I'm attempting to create my react app in VS code. After installing node.js (V 18.12.1), I ran the code to create my app and recieved the following response:

`npm create-react-app example`

`No version is set for command npm Consider adding one of the following versions in your config file at  nodejs 16.15.0 nodejs 16.17.0 nodejs 16.17.1 nodejs 16.18.0 nodejs 16.18.1`

I attempted the reinstall node.js and believe the issue may be due to the absence of my .tools-version file, but I don't know how to create it.

Comment: Open a terminal window in VS Code and enter: `npm -v` - report what you get back.

Comment: same response. "No version is set for command npm
Consider adding one of the following versions in your config file at 
nodejs 16.15.0
nodejs 16.17.0
nodejs 16.17.1
nodejs 16.18.0
nodejs 16.18.1"

Comment: How did you install NodeJS?

Comment: Through nodejs.org/en/

Comment: I'm using `asdf` and also seeing this exact error, but for `npx`

Answer (score 5):

Came here searching a very similar error. I had just got setup with a version manager, [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html), and installed NodeJS LTS (`asdf install nodejs lts`) before running an `npx` command and getting the error below.

```
No version is set for command npx
Consider adding one of the following versions in your config file at 
nodejs 18.12.1
nodejs lts
```

There's no path at the end of that second line  but given the error and [asdf instructions on setting a version](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_6-set-a-version), I configured a NodeJS version in the global `.tool-versions` file and that solved my issued:

```bash
echo "nodejs lts" >> $HOME/.tool-versions
```

Manu Jo Varghese has some great suggestions for checking your installation and environment! To add:

1. `which node`: find NodeJS program in your path
2. bash or zsh -> check which shell you're in, then check .bashrc or .zshrc files as fits

Answer (score 2):

I got same error and found an answer in [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/manage-node-js-versions-using-asdf/) link.

I will summarize the solution in short,

1. Install asdf and configure by following the steps given. asdf is runtime version manager
2. We need to add node.js plugin using asdf
3. Install specific verison using asdf
4. set global nodejs version using asdf
   `asdf global nodejs 14.17.6`

It resolved errors for npm and npx commands for nodejs version

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you are using a version of Node.js that does not include the npm command. In this case, you can try installing the npm command by running the following command:

```
npm install -g npm
```

or try these.

1. Verify that Node.js is installed correctly on your system by running the node -v command in a terminal. This should print the version number of Node.js if it is installed correctly.
2. Check if the npm command is in your system's PATH by running the
   which npm command in a terminal. This should print the full path to the npm executable if it is in your PATH.
3. If npm is not in your PATH, you can add it by modifying your PATH
   environment variable. You can do this by modifying your shell's
   profile file (e.g., ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, etc.), or by adding the path to the npm executable to your PATH manually.
4. If you have multiple versions of Node.js or npm installed on your
   system, you may need to update your PATH to point to the correct
   version. Alternatively, you can use a version manager such as nvm
   (Node Version Manager) to manage multiple versions of Node.js and
   npm on your system.

Try out and see!

Comment: npm command does not work for me. It would have to be installed a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
npx create-react-app example
```

Can see the detail in [official document](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html).

Comment: same response except with "npx" instead of "npm"